# Rigid body's collision stays in place

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, collision, rigidbody

Rigid body's collision stays in place even though the rigid body is moving. Because of this, the fabric catches on the void and rigid body passes through the fabric.[image: starting point]

[image: after simulation]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is: set the rigid body source to "base" then it works:

[image]

Note: i raised cloth quality steps to 9 for that sample.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Comment: you are welcome! nice animation by the way... ;)